# Pearson coefficients different for same data?

Tags: statistics, correlation, pearsons-correlation-coefficient, pearsons-coefficient

Is it possible to have different Pearson coefficients over the same input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pearson coefficient is the ratio between the covariance of two variables and the product of their standard deviations. If the data is same, their standard deviation, mean, covariance and hence Pearson coefficient will be same.
So, if you are calculating the Pearson coefficient between the same variables of same input data, then no, it can't be different.

Comment: but then how to explain I have different coefficients for same input?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: I am using this https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/correlation/PearsonsCorrelation.html#PearsonsCorrelation()

Comment: we can't really help you without data / hint about your code...